# How do I increase the number of merchants that come to my hall?

Tags: timber-and-stone

Does the number of merchants that come to my town hall depend on something? like the amount of gold or silver I have? or is it just completely random?

Edit:
I have three roads going in the cardinal directions. I have 50 gold, 43 silver, and 231 iron. How much more do I need?

Comment: To be technical the word you are looking for is Merchants, Trader is the proffesion your people have to interact with the Merchant.

Comment: Edited to Merchant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merchants will only appear if you have a road connecting to an edge of the map while also overlapping a square of a designated hall surface. Merchants much like immigrants will be more prone to appearing when you start accumulating wealth. Wealth is seen as iron, silver and gold ingots. As of 1.1 Merchants are more likely to appear if you connect roads to more then 1 side of the map maxing at 4 (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

I had got a merchant on day 1 in the afternoon without the road overlapping the hall.

In fact the road that does overlap doesn't seem to be getting any immigrants or merchants but, that could be due to chance. Wealth doesn't matter. Merchants will even come if you can't trade with that merchant as I have had two happen so far that I couldn't trade with.

In case you are wondering the same merchant may have multiple items to trade with you. I traded wood for feathers and wood for bronze ingot from the same merchant.